# Issue drawing triangles with basic VBO in OpenGL ES for Android 2.1

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am starting up work on an Android game and am learning OpenGL ES.  I have used OpenGL a bit, though it was quite some time ago by now.  I have mostly used DirectX lately with C++, so I understand graphic API concepts fairly well.

When, playing with the API on my own, I was unable to get the results I anticipated, I turned to [this](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) tutorial I found online that seemed fairly comprehensive, and though I understood it easily and followed the tutorial fairly strictly, I still can't get the screen to display a simple square (currently not using anything other than a vertex array with no colour).

Below is the code for my renderer class which I have been staring at for some time and am starting to go a little crazy with my inability to find my mistake.  I have done far more complicated things with graphics APIs (in both DirectX and OpenGL) so I find this kind of embarrassing and just need somebody to point out my probably glaringly obvious oversight.

Thank you in advance!

```
public class GameRenderer implements Renderer {

private float red, green, blue = 0.0f;

private final float vertices[] = {
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // 0, Bottom Right
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // 1, Top Right
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // 2, Top Left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // 3, Bottom Left
}; 

private final short indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3
};


private final float colours[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
}; 

FloatBuffer vFBuff;
FloatBuffer cFBuff;

ShortBuffer iSBuff;

public GameRenderer(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glClearColor(red, green, blue, 0.5f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -4f);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, iSBuff);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // set viewport
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

    ByteBuffer vBBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    ByteBuffer cBBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colours.length * 4);
    ByteBuffer iBBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);

    vFBuff = vBBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vFBuff.put(vertices);
    vFBuff.position(0);

    cFBuff = cBBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    cFBuff.put(colours);
    cFBuff.position(0);

    iSBuff = iBBuff.asShortBuffer();
    iSBuff.put(indices);
    iSBuff.position(0);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vFBuff);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
}

public void setColour(float r, float g, float b) {
    red = r;
    blue = b;
    green = g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.0f, 100.0f);
```

Don't set your `zNear` [to zero](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml):

> If `(r = zFar / zNear)` roughly `log2(r)` bits of depth buffer precision are lost.  Because `r` approaches infinity as zNear approaches 0, `zNear` must never be set to 0.

Comment: The reason it is currently set at 0 is because my original value (which was 10.0f, which is what I normally use in other projects) didn't work and 0.0f is what was used in the tutorial I was following which I assumed worked for the original author.  Either way, my square does not render.